# number of features reduced after libsvm scale

Tags: scale, libsvm

There were **1364** features in the file A (in the format of libsvm, e.g.  1 1:23 2:21 ... 1364:12 ) . 
we used the command:

> **./svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 -s A_range A > A_scale**

However, we saw **1362** features in A_scale (e.g. 1 1:0.171033 2:0.189956 3:0.0776929 ... 1362:0.084425). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some features with zero they would removed from the output and hence from the resulted file.

Comment: I reviwewed the file A. There were not features with zero value for each sample/row.

Comment: There were 1364 features in the file A (in the format of libsvm, e.g. 1 1:23 2:21 ... 1364:12 ) . we used the command: 
./svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 -s A_range A > A_scale 
However, we saw 1362 features in A_scale (e.g. 1 1:0.171033 2:0.189956 3:0.0776929 ... 1362:0.084425). 
Then, we tried 
./svm-scale -l -10 -u 10 -s A_range A > A_scale 
We got 1364 features/columns.

Comment: @Eman That sounds like when you did the scale to the range [0, 1], a couple of features fell into zero probably for a lack of numerical accuracy. In any case, values to close to zero are probably not going to make a big difference anyway

Comment: Thanks Pedrom. I found that libsvm did not save ZERO data. That is  1363:0.0  1364:0.0 .